# Syntax error when running query within batch script, same query works when i copy paste echo into new shell

Tags: batch-file

When i run a query within a batch script, it returns a syntax error:

`">" cannot be processed syntactically at this point.`

When i copy and paste the echo of the query into a new shell, it works like a charm:

`C:\tools>"C:\apps\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u foo -pbar -h foobar -e` 
`"SELECT ordernumber, IF(orderenddate<'2024-01-19 16:19:00' AND orderenddate<>'0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'completed', 'not completed')`
`as status FROM database.orders WHERE ordernumber='661891';"`

```
+----------------+-----------+
| ordernumber    | status    |
+----------------+-----------+
| 661891         | completed |
+----------------+-----------+
```

I know that `>` is used for redirection in batch scripting. For that reason i used caret (^) to escape it inside the query. The echo of the query doesn't contain the carets so the escaping definetly works.

Batch line:

```
set "query=SELECT ordernumber, IF(orderenddate^<'2024-01-19 16:19:00' AND orderenddate^<^>'0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'completed', 'not completed') as status ^
FROM database.orders WHERE ordernumber='!order!';"
```

Echo:

```
"C:\apps\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u foo -pbar -h foobar -e "SELECT ordernumber, IF(orderenddate<'2024-01-19 16:19:00' AND orderenddate<>'0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'completed', 'not completed') as status FROM database.orders WHERE ordernumber='661891';"
">" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Part in script where i pause, echo and run the query:

```
echo "%DB_MYSQL%" -u %DB_USER_CAURA% -p%DB_PASSWORD_CAURA% -h %DB_HOST_CAURA% -e "!query!"
call :Log "Executing database query..."
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`"%DB_MYSQL%" -u %DB_USER_CAURA% -p%DB_PASSWORD_CAURA% -h %DB_HOST_CAURA% -e "!query!"`) do (
        set "result=%%i"
        call :LogQuery "Databse query result: !result!"
    )
```

I have trouble understanding where this error originates from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you escape your `<` and `>` characters, you are only escaping them for the `set` command. You would then need to escape again for the parser of the `for` command. Essentially you'll need to escape your escape carets with more carets.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the answer. I put the whole query inside the `for` command, including carets. Nothing changed. So even if i escape `<` and `>` directly in the `for` command, i still get the same error.

Comment: I believe you need an extra set of escaped quotes. ```for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`^""%DB_MYSQL%" -u %DB_USER_CAURA% -p%DB_PASSWORD_CAURA% -h %DB_HOST_CAURA% -e "!query!"^"`) do (```

Comment: @Squashman This worked! But i don't exactly understand it. Would appreciate it if you could explain this in form of an answer so i can understand and accept it.